# Routing in Pyrocms is not working

Tags: routes, pyrocms

I am new to pyrocms and I am getting the 500 `An Error Was Encountered [ 500 ]`. I edited the routing file and add these two rules

`$route['admin/users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)']            = 'admin_index$1'; add
$route['admin/users/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(:any)?']            = 'admin_index$1';`

but both conflict with each other please help to understand this, why this is happening. I am new to pyrocms, that's why can't fix this.

Comment: The question is not clear as the context is not mentioned. BTW, are you sure you have enabled mod_rewrite in apache?